# Getting spam emails from my server

Tags: server, email, sendmail

I installed vesta panel on my ubuntu server a few months ago and then removed it for some reasons, today only I was setting up fail2ban and also setup sendmail on the server and now my Yahoo mail is full of emails from subject :

```
 Cron <admin@asinnetworks> sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue backup
```

body states

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

I do not have any folder name /usr/local/vesta/bin on my server I do not know how to stop my server from sending me these mails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Find the user with this cronjob

Thats the output from a cron job. do:

```
sudo grep -R "/usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue backup" /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

that will show hopefully what cron job is causing the output you can then ever delete it or direct its output to `/dev/null`

### Delete the cronjob

Okay now you know the user the cronjob is under you can remove it or silence it.

```
sudo crontab -u admin -e
```

then delete the line that contains `/usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue backup` this will stop the job happening this should not be a problem as you no longer use it.

### Or Silence the cronjob

or you can silence the output by adding the redirect as below:

```
*/5 * * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue backup > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I guess the mails stopped from coming let me wait for sometime and see. I will mar this answer as a solution then. As i typed this I got two emails again, plus grep -R "command" just waits on terminal and does nothing

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the grep -R command should not just wait, it should return nothing or the files that match?

Comment: Try the adjusted grep command

Comment: got this in return http://s8.postimg.org/4wmb20vcl/output.png

Comment: see adjusted answer.